# Product Two Independen Random Variables, Correct Argument?

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

Let's say we have a continuous RV $X \in \mathbb{R}$ and a discrete RV for example $Y \in \{1,2,3\}$, independent,  and we are interested in the distribution of the product of the two.

Please note that something similar was discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86293/how-to-compute-the-density-of-the-product-of-a-discrete-and-a-continuous-variabl), however i'm not sure if i understand the arguments in the solution, so here is my take:

\begin{equation*}
    \mathbb{P}(XY \leq x)  = \mathbb{P}(\{XY \leq x \} \cap \{\cup_{i=1}^3 Y = i \}) = \sum_{i=1}^3  \mathbb{P}(\{ XY \leq x \} \cap \{Y = i \}) = \sum_{i=1}^3  \mathbb{P}(Xi \leq x| {Y = i})\mathbb{P}(Y = i)
\end{equation*}

because $X$ and $Y$ are independent $\mathbb{P}(XY \leq x| Y = i) \overset{\text{bc \{Y = i \}}}{=} \mathbb{P}(Xi \leq x)$:

\begin{equation*}
\sum_{i=1}^3  \mathbb{P}(Xi \leq x| {Y = i})\mathbb{P}(Y = i) = \sum_{i=1}^3  \mathbb{P}(Xi \leq x)\mathbb{P}(Y = i) = \sum_{i=1}^3  \mathbb{P}(X \leq \frac{x}{i})\mathbb{P}(Y = i)
\end{equation*}

Comment: That is correct. The equality $P(Xi\leq x\mid Y=i)=P(Xi\leq x)$ is immediate by independence of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: ok thx. want to post this as an answer so i can close?

Comment: On your request I turned my comment into an answer.

Comment: much appreciated ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct.

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables then:

$$P(Xi\leq x\mid Y=i)=P(Xi\leq x)$$